# SharePoint Audit Log - List does not exist issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, auditing

I'm getting error "List does not exist" error when I try to enable Site Collection Audit settings. When I click on the Browse button under "Audit Log trimming" it throws an error "List does not exist". Usually the pop up form will display the SharePoint lists and content structure.

I found this solution in Technet forums. Will this help? Have anyone faced similar issue and fixed it.

Possible solution:-

> deactivate the Publishing feature at site collection and site level.
>   1st deactivate at site level and then deactiviate at Site collection level
>   2nd activate at site collection level and then activate site level.
>   Publishing Feature at site level: SharePoint Server Publishing & SharePoint Server Standard Site features
>   Publishing Feature at site Collection level: &  SharePoint Server Standard Site Collection features
>   this will reacreate the corrupted list.

Actual forum post.
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en/sharepointadminprevious/thread/078ae118-fe80-47b6-ac33-7af34cf55583

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deactivate and activate SharePoint Server Publishing at site collection and site level fixed this issue as mentioned in the link

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en/sharepointadminprevious/thread/078ae118-fe80-47b6-ac33-7af34cf55583